# Simple Spring Application working in Eclipse Server, but not deployed in Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to follow this Tutorial for a Simple Spring Application:

[http://notetipsblog.com/NoteTipsBlog/articles/spring3/mvc/spring_mvc_maven_eclipse_tutorial_1.html][1]

The Problem: it is not running from Eclipse inside the built-in Server (Tomcat 7), but when
I deploy the app as a .war in the same Tomcat instance, then it works perfectly.

I would not be astonished about the other way round, but here I don't even know where to
start looking, since the Tomcat is managed entirely by Eclipse (classpath etc.)

In the console output I cannot find anything wrong, it is even telling me that the
mapping that is used in the tutorial has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question: it turns out that it must have been some quirk, because
the next day, after restarting and redeploying, the thing worked.
Sorry for that.